# How to fix this Python tkinter problem with button Layout

Tags: python, image, button, tkinter, layout

I have made a game of rock paper scissors in python and everything was fine until I added the pics. Take a look at my code:

```
player_score=0
comp_score=0
def press():
    print("You Pressed ROCK")
    ent=1
    global player_score
    global comp_score
    for i in range(0,1):
        comp_ent=(random.randint(1,3))
    if comp_ent==3:
        print("You won...Computer Choose Scissors")
        player_score+=1
    elif comp_ent==2:
        print("You Lose...Computer Choose Paper")
        comp_score+=1
    else:
        print("It's a Draw...Computer Choose Rock")
    print("Player Score:",player_score)
    print("Computer Score:",comp_score)    
    print("\n")
def press1():
    print("You Pressed PAPER")
    ent=2
    global player_score
    global comp_score
    for i in range(0,1):
        comp_ent=(random.randint(1,3))
    if comp_ent==1:
        print("You won...Computer Choose Rock")
        player_score+=1
    elif comp_ent==3:
        print("You Lose...Computer Choose Scissors")
        comp_score+=1
    else:
        print("It's a Draw...Computer Choose Paper")
    print("Player Score:",player_score)
    print("Computer Score:",comp_score)
    print("\n")
def press2():
    print("You Pressed SCISSORS")
    ent=3
    global player_score
    global comp_score    
    for i in range(0,1):
        comp_ent=(random.randint(1,3))
    if comp_ent==2:
        print("You won...Computer Choose Paper")
        player_score+=1
    elif comp_ent==1:
        print("You Lose...Computer Choose Rock")
        comp_score+=1
    else:
        print("It's a Draw...Computer Choose Scissors")
    print("Player Score:",player_score)
    print("Computer Score:",comp_score)    
    print("\n")
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
photo1=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Abhinav\Desktop\Important Folder\Python Project\rock2.gif")
photo2=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Abhinav\Desktop\Important Folder\Python Project\paper2.gif")
photo3=PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Users\Abhinav\Desktop\Important Folder\Python Project\scissors 2.gif")
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.pack()
button = tk.Button(root)
button.config(image=photo1,width="300",height="200",text="ROCK",fg="Black",command=press)
button.pack(side=TOP)
button2 = tk.Button(root)
button.config(image=photo2,width="300",height="200",text="PAPER",fg="Blue",command=press1)
button2.pack(side=BOTTOM)
button3 = tk.Button(root)
button3.config(image=photo3,width="300",height="200",text="SCISSORS",fg="Green",command=press2)
button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button3.config(image=photo3)
root.mainloop()
```

I am doing this for my school project.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyKJz.png)

Comment: I would recommend reading the follow article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. This meta post is also relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question. As an aside, I think the design of the program could be improved, especially in regards to the use of global variables.

Comment: Oke, it didn't work. But did you get any error message?

Comment: No it shows as just the screen shot...and when I click the small button also there is no output..

Comment: Please do not add copy+paste waffle just to skip past the question filter.

Comment: Okay...sorry it was my first time using stackoverflow for a question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have misspelled `button2` as `button` in `button.config(image=photo2,...)`.  It should be `button2.config(image=photo2, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked...I spent an hour trying to figure it out...thanks again